# Trying to identify a tv series from the early 80's about a man who came from the Sun?

Tags: story-identification, tv

I am hoping I can find an answer here  to a  question that has plagued me for many years.I vividly remember a tv show that was on in the early 80's when I was a small child.I can't remember that much except that it's plot was about a man who came to Earth from the Sun.Somehow he had actually lived on the Sun and was a native from there.About the only other thing I can remember is that he of course didn't want humans to find out his secret and I recall a scene where he is being chased through the woods in the afternoon by humans and possibly dogs and as he sees the Sun through the trees as he is running he keeps longing for home.I can't remember the years it was on but I would guess 1980-1983? I believe it was a short lived series.
I know this show existed as what I described has been strongly in my memory all this time but I can't find out anything about it.Searches turn up nothing.I would so love to find out the name of this program so I could discover it again.Any help would be appreciated.Thanks much!

Comment: Can you include details other than plot?  Like what country this was in?  Even whether it was syndicated or in prime time?

Comment: Hi.I'm sorry I left those out.This was in the USA and it came out at night.It also was probably on one of the three big networks as those were the only TV channels my parents and I received until my late teenage years.Thanks.

Comment: Dear Paul A.Clayton,

Comment: I know this has already been answered, but this brought to mind the film Northstar :- http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0091650/

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It sounds like you *might* be referring to [The Phoenix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Phoenix_%281982_TV_series%29).  (It was shown on the SciFi channel some years ago, if I recall correctly.)  Although the protagonist is not listed as "from the Sun", he did receive power by an amulet being exposed to sunlight.  According to the wikipedia article, the show was broadcast in 1982 (so that fits) and only the pilot and four other episodes were filmed and broadcast.

There are several few episodes on Youtube [hat tip to dave]

Ep. 3 - [One of Them](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zyWD6QPcy3M)
Ep. 4 - [A Presence of Evil](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-SnXPa2V04s)
Ep. 5 - [The Fire Within](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z3BkwaJPxiM)

Comment: I swear sometimes I think I must be older than what I'm lead to believe. Just by a few years, because I remember this show and others so well, and more than a few only aired before I was born or the year I was born. But yeah, it's The Phoenix, not even remotely a good show.

Comment: Clayton,YES! I do believe that is it.Thank you so much.Although , the details are a little different than I remember I believe this must be it.This website is amazing.It brought over 30 years of wondering to a close in one day.One more question -Paul, is this available on DVD? I would love to own it.Thanks again!

Comment: Well,Mr.Mcquarie that is a matter of opinion.I feel there must have been something of value to it for it to stick in my mind for all these years as it has. And seeing as how as an adult I'm seriously into the ancient world,archaeology, sacred science etc, it seems as if it is something I would enjoy watching as an adult as well. Your mileage obviously varies.

Comment: @SpikeBuffyLuv Based on the "reviews" on amazon.com (http://www.amazon.com/The-Phoenix-1981-TVseries/product-reviews/B001992O14/ref=dp_top_cm_cr_acr_txt?ie=UTF8&showViewpoints=1), it has not been released on DVD.

Comment: Thank you for the  second reply Paul.Hopefully someday it will come out on the home video market.

Comment: This was a great show!!!!!!

Comment: My favorite show at the time...too bad it was only 4 episodes.